# Apple migration assistant hangs at end

Tags: migration-assistant

I'm trying to migrate one Mac mini to another. Both have Snow Leopard, and I'm migrating via ethernet. The process seems nearly complete, but it's been on a screen saying "Transferring your time zone setting... less than a minute remaining" for 20 mins now

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have no answers, but I am experiencing this as well. Migrating from an existing Mac Mini to a new one.
One thing of note - When I tried to install the Migration Assistant from the media included with the new Mac, it failed stating that the version on the existing Mac was newer. I'm wondering if there's some version conflict.

In the end, I backed the old Mini up to a time machine and restored from there successfully.